# Redirecting native dll stdout/stderr from within C#

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, pipe, stdout

I'm trying to redirect the output of a third-party native dll which outputs to stdout/stderr from within C#. The output of both stdout and stderr should go to a log file.

Here's my idea (x2 for two streams):

- Create an [AnonymousPipeServerStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.anonymouspipeserverstream.aspx)
- Get the pipe's handle via `_outServer.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle()`
- Use P/Invoke to call [SetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244%28VS.85%29.aspx) with said handle
- Create an [AnonymousPipeClientStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.anonymouspipeclientstream.aspx) connected to the server stream
- Create a thread to sit in a loop reading from the `AnonymousPipeClientStream` and outputting to the logger.
- Periodically call `flush` on the `AnonymousPipeServerStream`

So all this seems to be working well... within my code. As soon as control passes to the native DLL, everything goes back to stderr! If need be, I can debug into the native DLL and see what's going wrong, but... I'd really rather not, so does anyone have any ideas before I spend 10 hours trying to figure out how handles work?

For reference, the test code is at: http://pastebin.com/f3eda7c8. The interesting stuff is lines 58-89 in the constructor. (I'll add error handling, etc. later, of course).

Comment: The code at pastebin.com seems to have some bugs. E.g. the char buffer "_buffer" is used in two threads...

Comment: @Stiefel - Oops, yeah, it does. I threw that together pretty quickly, IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it, though the solution (of course) has very little to do with the problem. The dll was compiled in mingw, which apparently doesn't respect the handles used by the MSVC runtime.

I'll leave the code & solution up in case anyone else encounters this problem.

Comment: So is there a way to make this work when calling into a MnGW compiled dll from C#? Does your pastebin solution work or is there something else?

Answer (score 0):

Using the code at https://pastebin.com/f3eda7c8 I've got it to work on Windows 10 and within a Windows LTSC 2019 container.  However, it captures *only* the Console output of the C# code, not a trace of the unmanaged DLL's printf output which is the outcome that I desire to reach.  I had to use the hack below after the SetStdHandle assignments in order to get it work - a hack that I do not really like BTW.

Could anyone please enlighten me on what is missing for me to get it to redirect the printf output to the Console that originates from the native .DLL?  Do I need to add a `fflush(stdout / stderr)` after each `[f]printf` statement? Or just `fflush(stdout);` and `fflush(stderr);` before the function I'm interested in seeing its output returns?  As a matter of fact I added a couple of `fflush(stdout);` calls after lines I am seeing in the container's output but none of those native `printf` pieces of information got redirected.

````
        private void _ResetConsoleOutStream()
        {
            //Force console to recreate its output stream the next time Write/WriteLine is called
            typeof(Console).GetField("_out", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                           .SetValue(null, null);
        }```
````