# Is it still possible these days for a C# program to capture the stdout of a native DLL?

Tags: c#, interop, stdout, native

I have a Console C# application that calls into a native DLL whose output I want to capture.

I started off from the solution in this post [Redirecting native dll stdout/stderr from within C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430213/redirecting-native-dll-stdout-stderr-from-within-c-sharp) but so far could capture only the output of my own C# program, none of the native DLL's.  The original post dates back to 2009 so I'm wondering if it is still possible to do that these days?

Comment: `Console.SetOut(someTextWriter)` maybe?

Comment: Thanks very much @Charlieface!  I did try it recently and it did not work for capturing native code output, but it did capture the managed code's output.